# Calculate difference where numid is the same between datasets of differing length

Tags: r, for-loop, compare

I have 2 data frames: "start.date" and "death.date". Each include 2 columns "numid" (a numeric id) and a "date" column. "start.date" is a dataset that records start of disease for each numid. "death.date" includes only those numid in "start.date" that died on the date in death.date$date.

I need to calculate the difference (=survival) between start.date and death.date for those with the same numid.

This is what I wrote:

```
 tempi<-as.numeric(factor(start.date$numid))
 tempj<-as.numeric(factor(death.date$numid))
 for(i in tempi){
   for(j in tempj){
     surviv[i]<-ifelse(colic.date$numid[i]==death.date$numid[j],
                         death.date$date.death[j]-colic.date$date.colic[i],
                         "alive")
   }  
 }
```

My issue here I think is that surviv[i] only keeps the last value of death.date$numid[j] but I can not find a way out. Anyone could shine some light on this please?
There are probably easier ways to do this (it runs very slow - even with the wrong result)

Apologies if this is has been discussed somewhere I just could not find anything that works with my data.

Cheers
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my stab at it, using a custom function to generate dates and then created two data.frames. I then found common.ids between the data.frames using `intersect`, and used `difftime` to find the difference in dates. Your code is slow as you're using for loops. Read the resources on [this page](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/tutorials/impatient-r/more-r-vectorize/) for vectorizing your code.

I used `intersect`, though have a look at `%in%` as well to find common items.

```
#Function to get some dates, using a uniform distribution,
thanks to [Dirk Eddelbuettel][2]
unif.dates <-function(N, start = "2012/01/01", end = "2012/12/31") {
#Orginal at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14721124/2747709
start <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(start))#
end <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(end))#
dt <- as.numeric(difftime(end,start,unit = "sec"))#
ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))#
rt <- start + ev
}
#Generating some random ids and dates and 
assigning them to data.frames

start.date <- data.frame(numid = sample(25,15), date = unif.dates(15, start = "2012/06/01", end = "2012/12/31"))

death.date <- data.frame(numid = sample(25,15),date = unif.dates(15, start = "2012/08/01", 
end = "2013/02/28"))
#Get Common ids between data.frames
common.ids <-intersect(death.date$numid,start.date$numid)
#Calculate time difference, this defauts to days, read ?difftime for other units
z <-difftime(death.date$date[death.date$numid %in% common.ids], start.date$date[start.date$numid %in% common.ids])
```

Comment: Thank you @Infominer for the suggestion. I had used %in% initially but could not make it work in this instance, but in the end your code worked for me. One if the issues was that even though I had specified the dates as.POSIXct in the original datasets then R reconverted these to numbers (not sure why) when I was using cbind to merge these date columns between the original datasets. So I got around it by first cbind-ing the columns with the date as.character() and then converted the date to as.POSIXct() just before using difftime(). Thanks for your help!