# Why do i got different results using SE or NSE dplyr functions

Tags: r, dplyr, standard-evaluation

Hi I got differents results from dplyr function when I use standard evaluation through lazyeval package.

Here is how to reproduce something close to my real datas with 250k rows and about 230k groups. I would like to group by id1, id2 and subset the rows with the max(datetime) for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
# random datetime generation function by Dirk Eddelbuettel
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720983/efficiently-generate-a-random-sample-of-times-and-dates-between-two-dates
rand.datetime <- function(N, st = "2012/01/01", et = "2015/08/13") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev
}

set.seed(42)
# Creating 230000 ids couples
ids <- data_frame(id1 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(23e4, 9, pattern = "[0-9]"), 
                  id2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(23e4, 9, pattern = "[0-9]"))
# Repeating randomly the ids[1:2000, ] to create groups    
ids <- rbind(ids, ids[sample(1:2000, 20000, replace = TRUE), ])
datas <- mutate(ids, datetime = rand.datetime(25e4))
```

When I use the NSE way I got 230000 rows

```
df1 <- 
  datas %>% 
  group_by(id1, id2) %>% 
  filter(datetime == max(datetime))
nrow(df1) #230000
```

But when I use the SE, I got only 229977 rows

```
ids <- c("id1", "id2")
filterVar <- "datetime"
filterFun <- "max"
df2 <- 
  datas %>% 
  group_by_(ids) %>% 
  filter_(.dots = lazyeval::interp(~var == fun(var), 
                                   var = as.name(filterVar), 
                                   fun = as.name(filterFun)))
nrow(df2) #229977
```

My two pieces of code are equivalent right ?
Why do I experience different results ? Thanks.

Comment: I think you forgot to specify the `.dots` argument in the `group_by_` - `.dots = ids`.

Comment: Indeed, I have 230000 rows with group_by(.dots = ids). I wonder what this is computing without the .dots argument then.

Comment: Looks like maybe it just takes the first in the vector.  See the number of rows when you group by `id1` only.

Comment: You are totaly right `length(unique(datas$id1)) #229977`. If you add it as an answer I would be glad to accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the `.dots` argument in `group_by_` when giving a vector of column names.

```
df2 <- datas %>% 
    group_by_(.dots = ids) %>% 
    filter_(.dots = lazyeval::interp(~var == fun(var), 
                               var = as.name(filterVar), 
                               fun = as.name(filterFun)))
nrow(df2)
[1] 230000
```

It looks like `group_by_` might take the first column name from the vector as the only grouping variable when you don't specify the `.dots` argument.  You can check this by grouping on `id1` only.

```
df1 <- datas %>% 
    group_by(id1) %>% 
    filter(datetime == max(datetime))
 nrow(df1)
[1] 229977
```

(If you group just on `id2` the number of rows is 229976).