# find the shortest time difference between two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have two dataframes,

```
df1

id        time1
1         2016-04-07 21:39:10
1         2016-04-05 11:19:17
2         2016-04-03 10:58:25
2         2016-04-02 21:39:10

df2

id        time2
1         2016-04-07 21:39:11
1         2016-04-05 11:19:18
1         2016-04-06 21:39:11
1         2016-04-04 11:19:18
2         2016-04-03 10:58:26
2         2016-04-02 21:39:11
2         2016-04-04 10:58:26
2         2016-04-05 21:39:11
```

I want to find for each entry in df1, the shortest time difference in df2. Suppose we take the first entry, it has id 1, so I want to loop through df2, filter for id 1, then check the time difference between one entry of df1 and remaining entries of df2 and find the shortest difference and fetch the corresponding entry. My sample output should be

```
id        time                   time2                    diff(in secs)
1         2016-04-07 21:39:10    2016-04-07 21:39:10        1
1         2016-04-05 11:19:17    2016-04-05 11:19:17        1
2         2016-04-03 10:58:25    2016-04-03 10:58:25        1
2         2016-04-02 21:39:10    2016-04-02 21:39:10        1
```

the following is my try,

```
for(i in unique(df1$id)){
  temp1 = df1[df1$id == i,]
  temp2 = df2[df2$id == i,]
  for(j in unique(df1$time1){
     for(k in unique(df2$time2){
        diff = abs(df1$time1[j] - df2$time2[k]
        print(diff)}}}
```

I am not able to progress after this, getting many errors. Can anybody help me in correcting this? May be suggest a better efficient way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

Reproducable data:

```
    df1 <- data.frame(
        id = c(1,1,2,2),
        time1 = c('2016-04-07 21:39:10', '2016-04-05 11:19:17', '2016-04-03 10:58:25', '2016-04-02 21:39:10')
    )

    df2 <- data.frame(
        id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
        time2 = c('2016-04-07 21:39:11', '2016-04-05 11:19:18','2016-04-07 21:39:11', '2016-04-05 11:19:18', '2016-04-03 10:58:26', '2016-04-02 21:39:11','2016-04-03 10:58:26', '2016-04-02 21:39:11')
    )

df1$time1 =  as.POSIXct(df1$time1)
df2$time2 = as.POSIXct(df2$time2)
```

Comment: Can you please add the code to generate `df1` and `df2`

Comment: do the `id`s matter at all?? sounds like shortest difference within `id`

Comment: @jaimedash yes along with the corresponding times

Comment: @Divi yeah will do it

Comment: Please provide data using `dput`.

Comment: @Lmo Can u suggest how to create this in data. I am relatively new to R. I created this dummy data by typing.

Comment: @Divi Can u suggest how to create this in data. I am relatively new to R. I created this dummy data by typing.

Comment: write `dput(df1)` and paste the output. do the same with `df2`

Comment: Here is a good link on [creating a reproducible dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @lmo Just updated the question.

Comment: @Divi Just updated the question.

Comment: @jaimedash Just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `dplyr`. Basically the idea is since we want to produce an entry we'll assign each element in `df1` a new id (in this case I just called it rowname).

After this, all we're interested in is joining the two dataframes on the `id` and filter them based on the minimum absolute difference.

```
library(dplyr)

df1$time1 <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df1$time1))
df2$time2 <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df2$time2))

df1 %>% 
  add_rownames("rowname") %>%
  left_join(df2, "id") %>% 
  mutate(diff=time2-time1) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  filter(min(abs(diff)) == abs(diff)) %>% 
  distinct
```

This is my output:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
Groups: rowname [4]

  rowname    id               time1               time2   diff
    (chr) (dbl)              (time)              (time) (dfft)
1       1     1 2016-04-07 21:39:10 2016-04-07 21:39:11 1 secs
2       2     1 2016-04-05 11:19:17 2016-04-05 11:19:18 1 secs
3       3     2 2016-04-03 10:58:25 2016-04-03 10:58:26 1 secs
4       4     2 2016-04-02 21:39:10 2016-04-02 21:39:11 1 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in base R. To generate random dates (useful), I borrowed and edited a nice function from [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720983/efficiently-generate-a-random-sample-of-times-and-dates-between-two-dates):

```
latemail <- function(N, st="2011/01/01", et="2016/12/31") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  return(st + ev)
}
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2), time1=latemail(4))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4)), time2=latemail(8))
```

And then your answer can be achieved in two lines:

```
shortest <- sapply(df1$time1, function(x) which(abs(df2$time2 - x) == min(abs(df2$time2 - x))))
cbind(df1, df2[shortest,])
```

Output:

```
id               time1 id               time2
 1 2011-10-08 02:00:21  1 2011-08-17 18:07:47
 1 2012-05-06 17:49:03  1 2012-09-04 19:52:40
 2 2013-10-29 13:14:51  1 2012-10-29 20:09:31
 2 2016-06-17 19:23:43  2 2015-11-24 02:07:15
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(
  id = c(1,1,2,2),
  time1 = c('2016-04-07 21:39:10', '2016-04-05 11:19:17', '2016-04-03 10:58:25', '2016-04-02 21:39:10')
)

df2 <- data.table(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  time2 = c('2016-04-07 21:39:11', '2016-04-05 11:19:18','2016-04-07 21:39:11', '2016-04-05 11:19:18', '2016-04-03 10:58:26', '2016-04-02 21:39:11','2016-04-03 10:58:26', '2016-04-02 21:39:11')
)

df1$time1 =  as.POSIXct(df1$time1)
df2$time2 = as.POSIXct(df2$time2)

res <- df1[df2, .(time1, time2), by  = .EACHI, on = "id"][, diff:= abs(time2 -time1)]
setkey(res, id, time1, diff)
res <- res[, row := seq_along(.I), by = .(id, time1)][row == 1]
```