# How to iterate over columns quickly, checking for things along the way (R)

Tags: r, loops, foreach, data.table, dplyr

I have a bit of a unique question. I've tried a few different things which I'll detail after the problem itself.

**The problem:**
For each user ID, I need to iterate through event dates and check if each date is within 30 days of the next date. I have 260,000 records, and a not-insignificant number of IDs only have a single entry. The data look like:

```
id |    date1   |   date2
1  | 2016-01-01 | 2016-02-12
```

and so on

**I have tried:**

- foreach (split out each ID's set of events, calculate, recombine; ran into memory issues).
- data.table, but I don't know enough to know if I exhausted this option.
- briefly dplyr (namely:

  ```
  mutate(time_btwn=abs(as.numeric(difftime(data$date,lag(data$date2,1),"days")))))
  ```
- and I'm currently running a straight for loop that iterates through all rows. It is extremely slow and I wish I didn't have to do it.  The code:

  ```
  for ( i in 2:nrow(data) ){
      if ( data$id[ i ] != data$id[ i - 1 ] ){
          next
      } else {
          data$timebtwn[i] <- abs( as.numeric( difftime( data$date1[i], data$date2[ i - 1 ], "days" ) ) )
      }
  }
  ```

I've looked into apply and lapply, but can't quite work out the function to plug into apply or lapply that will do what I need (i.e. for each entry in column1, check one row back in column2 and return the difference between the dates IF both rows have the same id).

Is there a faster way than a straight for loop (or a way using foreach) that is fast and not memory intensive?

Comment: Can you `dput()` an example of your data?

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of columns you need to operate on, and therefore need to melt to long so you can operate on a single column. Long in this case may be _very_ long, though, so workarounds may be appropriate.

Comment: Not without interrupting the for loop I mentioned. The data is literally what I said, though. ID, date1, date2. Sorry :( If and when it finishes I'll update the post.

Comment: Do you need a boolean vector that says whether each row has a difference less than or equal to 30? You could easily create a new date_diff column and then just check whether it's less than or equal to 30.

Comment: You should make the code in question reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have a sample dataset to work with, I had to make one up, and thus it is difficult to know what exactly you are after, but:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# generate random date samples
latemail <- function(N, st="2012/01/01", et="2015/12/31") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- as_date(st + ev)
}

set.seed(42)
mydat<-data.table(id = as.character(sample.int(1000, 10000, replace =T)),
                  date1 = as_date(latemail(10000)),
                  date2 = as_date(latemail(10000)))
setkey(mydat, id)

mydat[, .(timebtw = abs( as.numeric(difftime(date1, date2), "days" )),
          date1 = date1,
          date2 = date2), by = id]

#     id timebtw      date1      date2
#1:   1       4 2012-01-15 2012-01-11
#2:   1       2 2012-03-21 2012-03-19
#3:   1       9 2012-10-01 2012-10-10
#4:   1       1 2013-08-08 2013-08-09
#5:   1       9 2014-02-11 2014-02-02
#---                                  
#9996: 999       7 2014-10-28 2014-11-04
#9997: 999       9 2015-03-28 2015-04-06
#9998: 999       0 2015-07-22 2015-07-22
#9999: 999      10 2015-09-06 2015-09-16
#10000: 999       8 2015-10-03 2015-10-11
```

I got the date generating function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720983/efficiently-generate-a-random-sample-of-times-and-dates-between-two-dates) nice post. Let me know if this is what you are trying to do. This example has 10,000 rows and 999 unique ids. To illustrate the speed:

```
system.time(
    mydat[, .(timebtw = abs( as.numeric(difftime(date1, date2), "days")),
              date1 = date1,
              date2 = date2), by = id])
#user  system elapsed 
#0.26    0.00    0.26
```

Comment: It isn't, I'm sorry :(

I need to find the difference between date1 from row i and date2 from row i+1, and insert that into row i of the new column.

Comment: I worked it out! data.table actually isn't the way to go. All I needed was

data <- group_by(data, id) %>% mutate(time_btwn = abs( as.numeric( difftime( date2, lead(date1,1), units = "days" ) ) ) )

And that's all. Wild!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.