# Sample time between time range 08:00:00 and 15:00:00

Tags: r

How to sample the time between the specified range (08:00:00 to 15:00:00).
Please help!

Code I tried, but raises error

```
sample(seq(as.Date.POSIXct('08:00:00'), as.Date.POSIXct('15:00:00')), 20)
```

Expected:

```
[1] "08:01:00" "14:00:50" "12:49:50"
```

Comment: It's `as.Date.POSIXct()` causing the error, not `sample()`.

Comment: Very related (possible duplicate) - [efficiently generate a random sample of times and dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720983/efficiently-generate-a-random-sample-of-times-and-dates-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create sequence of times within the specific duration and `sample`. The time would have todays date, to get only time component we use `format`.

```
all_times <- format(seq(as.POSIXct('08:00:00', format = "%T"), 
                         as.POSIXct('15:00:00', format = "%T"), by = "sec"), "%T")

sample(all_times, 3)  
#[1] "11:51:16" "09:50:10" "13:09:21"
```